# Confirmation Dialogbox not disappering after confirmation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog box and two command buttons. After clicking on the option, the dialog box is not disappearing. Below is the code Snippet. I am using the `confirmation.hide()` option.

```
<p:confirmDialog
    message="Are you sure about deleting the substudyplan?"
    id="confirmation"
    header="Confirmation Deleting substudyplan" severity="alert"
    appendToBody="TRUE" widgetVar="cd">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure"
                 actionListener="#{editBean.deleteSubStudyPlan(selectedRow)}"  
                 update=":studyPlanEditForm"
             oncomplete="confirmation.hide()" />
        <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide();"
        type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Does your 'Not Yet' button work when you click it? Is it only the 'Yes Sure' button that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

your `widgetVar` is *cd*

so you should access it with its name when you try to  use it

So , change `confirmation.hide()` to `cd.hide()`

Or , rename `widgetVar` from *cd* to *confirmation*

Also, by looking at this [ConfirmDialog inside form does not closes with update @form](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17546) , you might want to narrow the `update=":studyPlanEditForm"` to `update=":someOtherWrapperInsideForm"`

Comment: Hi, I changed it.But it did not work. actionListener is getting invoked.But dialog box not getting closed.

Comment: weird , try replacing `appendToBody="TRUE"` with appendToBody="true" , also any chance you got nested forms ? (form inside form)

Comment: Hi No nested form;Changed the same to appendToBody="true" but not working.

Comment: just for a test , rename the `cd` to a longer an uniqe name like `mycustomvar` and try again, if that wont help try removing `appendToBody="true"`

Comment: also, if you use `appendToBody="true"` then add `h:form` inside your confirmDialog

Answer (score 0):

Try `onclick` instead of `oncomplete`.
In my experience `onsuccess`, `onerror` and `oncomplete` don't always work as expected.

Comment: Hi I solved the problem using a simple dialog instead of confirmation dialog.

Comment: Glad to her that!
I'm new to stackoverflow and have not asked a question yet. Maybe you should mark it as solved somehow.